# WPF project won't build after port to dot net core 3.1

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I'm in the middle of trying to move a WPF application from .Net 4.8 to .Net Core 3.1.
I've been following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/migration/convert-project-from-net-framework) article and now am stuck with build errors that I can't diagnose.

I suppose my question really is "How do I diagnose the root cause of the build issue?" but I'm not particularly expert with WPF/XAML.

The main issue presents itself as The name XXXX doesn't exist in the namespace YYYY but I think this is really because the dll isn't getting built for some other reason and therefore isn't "reference-able".

[image: XAML reference issue]

Also in the code-behind for this page, I get this: -

[image: XAML referebce issue 2]

...which is due to the missing auto generated .i.g.cs file presumably because the build didn't get to it.
I can't seem to find any indication as to what the root cause is though, I turned up the build log verbosity and nothing jumped out.

I've spent a lot of time on SO and google and done the following which didn't help: -

1. delete the bin / obj / .vs folders
2. reboot
3. launch VS as admin and try again
4. checked the build config as it needs to be x86 due to some dependent
   libraries

One suggestion I have not tried is to comment out the XAML with the issue because these are all over the project and would take a long long time.

I'm hopeful that this is something trivial that I've done/not done but how can I find the real reason for the project not building?

Comment: When you look in the errors list. Often you have one problem stops compilation and causes other errors. Look at the bottom error and fix that.

Comment: All the errors were related to the X doesn't exist in Y....To follow your advice, I went through a couple of errors and used intellisense to re-add the same items in the xaml (without changing the actual xaml). After each time, I would rebuild and get a seemlingly random selection of new X doesn't exist in Y errors. So I would do the same... re-add using intellisense and rebuild. I did nothing else for a couple of mins and now it's rebuilt successfully. I'm completely baffled and still have no idea what was the blocker. Is my xaml experience in VS unusual? anyway, thank you!

Comment: @Jon my WPF project sometimes gets stuck and doesnt compile with the same error. Restarting VS usually does the trick. If you want to know what happend, look into the building process for WPF. You have a ```.xaml``` and a ```.cs```-file. The compiler auto-generates a ```.g.cs```-file which contains the ```InitilizeComponent()```. [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/building-a-wpf-application-wpf)